# Need Solution for multiple slf4j binding without removing other binding jars from classpath

Tags: java, apache-spark, logging, logback, slf4j

In my project i'm using logback as my default logger. But now after integrating it into another project which is basically a spark project my logger getting class cast exception because of mutiple slf4j binding in classpath.

Here the **spark project(parent project)** using log4j as default logger and it uses SLF4j-LOG4j2.jar for slf4j implementation.

**My project(child project)** is using logback which includes SLF4j implementation internally.

I know the problem is because of 2 StaticBinder class in the classpath and it takes the first one(log4jbinder from spark) as it is the default behavior.
but i need all jars in classpath.

What i have tried so far:

- I have created custom Staticbinder inside org.slf4j.impl package to
  redirect to logback inside my project. but it doesn't worked when
  converts my project as jar and included in parent project.
- Tried many ways to change the Loggercontext to use logback. but not
  worked.

**So finally i want to know whether can we able to change the slf4j binding to logback at run time or any other solution is there without removing anything in classpath?**

In my classpath parent project:

- log4j-1.2.17.jar
- slf4j-log4j12-1.7.16.jar (Should not be removed)

Child project:

- slf4j-api-1.7.16.jar
- logback-classic-1.1.8.jar (should not be removed)

Comment: Why can't you just **exclude** the dependency when using it in your other project? I assume (and hope) you're using a tool like maven or gradle which has exclusion features exactly for that purpose.

Comment: But if we exclude logback in my project then logback configurations which are present won't work.

Comment: Are you using ivy, gradle or maven or something like that?

Comment: Ya I'm using maven in my project...in parent project they using Gradle... But exclude things will not work here.. because we need both..

Comment: You need to make a choice, or all your projects need to use logback, or you need to write an equivalent log4j configuration for the other project.

Answer (score 1):

Are you aware of [log4j-over-slf4j](https://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html#log4j-over-slf4j) artifact? You would need to add it to the child project and [**exclude**](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html) both `slf4j-log4j12.jar` and `log4j-1.2.17.jar` **in your child project**. That way, calls to log4j from your parent project would be redirected to slf4j.

However, as your question indicates, if it is the child project which gets included into the parent project, then you should **not export** your choice of logging framework, in this case logback, to the parent. You can achieve this by splitting the child into a library part (which gets included in the parent) and a stand-alone java application part which can depend on logback.

Thus, your project structure becomes *P* (for parent), *cL* (for child library) and *cSA* (for child standalone). *P* declares a dependency on *cL* plus *slf4j-log4j12* (with *slf4j-api* and *log4j* included transitively) and also include a `log4j.properties` file to configure logging in *P*. Project *cSA* declares a dependency on *cL* plus *logback-classic* (with *slf4j-api* and *logback-core* included transitively) and also include `logback.xml` file to configure logging in *cSA*.

Comment: Thanks for your response.. But the problem is we won't be able to exclude classpath jars(which spark loads in parent project) in child project using maven. I'm able to do changes only in child project.

Also I tried adding  this jar in my dependency but it creates log4jDelegationLoop exception because of circular binding. I know it's expected when we do without excluding slf4j-log4j2.jar.
So still looking for solution.

Comment: Exclusion is done within your child project. Added a link on how to do it in my answer above.

Comment: Hi Ceki, I think I'm not clear on my explanation about my project.
Let me explain you clearly..

Basically my project is an standalone jar which includes logback as a logging framework..
Here we are having only 2 dependency slf4j API and logback for logging. 
Parent project is not included as a dependency inside my pom to exclude transient dependencies in it.

My parent project is based on spark which is basically using log4j as default logging framework. Here I won't able to change anything.

I'll generate my standalone project as jar and they include this into their project.

Comment: I see . Updated my answer.

Comment: But we need child project logs to get generated even after integrating it in Parent project when using verbose mode.So that we get some information on what exactly happening in Child project. Just want to know can we achieve this by having **custom LoggerContext** class which sets logback into context or can we have **2 logger configuration** in single project(Child project)? So that we will check in loggerfactory and set the right configuration to it. @Ceki Once again thanks for your continuous support on this.